# Credit attribution and use of basemap

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, carto, basemap, license

I am using a basemap ([http://basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_nolabels/{z}/{x}/{y}.png](http://basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_nolabels/%7Bz%7D/%7Bx%7D/%7By%7D.png)) in QGIS to draw a map for a scientific paper.

I am trying to understand who is the "owner" of this map and who should I credit to.
Also I would like to know what license this basemap has (CC by 4.0,others?)

If you open the basemap on your browser at http://basemaps.cartocdn.com/#11/50.2342/-66.4254
you can see at the right bottom corner

> "Leaflet| (c) OpenStreetmap contibutors, (c) rastertiles/voyager"

when clicking on "(c) OpenStreetmap" I am sent to OpenStreetmap website, clearly.
when clicking on "(c) rastertiles/voyager" I am sent to CARTO.com.

Is it CARTO.com or OpenStreetMap ?

PS: I wrote to CARTO.com via their website form but the only thing I got was a marketing mailing list inscription...

Comment: The map based on OSM and is deliverd with CARTO styles and technology. To be on a safe side, I would suggest to use both. For OSM you can use "© OpenStreetMap contributors" and for CARTO you should have a look to this page: https://carto.com/help/tutorials/publishing-and-sharing-maps/